# How to count total same words in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, knuth-morris-pratt

I've tried to compare words from database and input form. I wanna count the same words, but the result is not correct.

> Input : method or algorithm

tb_keyword

```
id      key
1      method
2     algorithm
```

result

> 1

expected result

> 2

codes :

```
include_once("kmp.php");
$kata = '';
if(isset($_GET['kata']))
  $kt = $_GET['kata'];
?>
<div style="width:600px;">
<form method="get" action="">
Cari Kata : <input type="text" name="kata" value="<?php echo $kata; ?>" /
<input type="submit" value="Cari">
</form>
</div>
<?php
$kata = explode(' ',$kt); 
foreach($kata as $katas){
$total = 0;
$KMP = new KMP();
$art = $db_con->prepare("select * from tb_positive_keywords");
$art->execute();
while($teks = $art->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
if($kata!=''){
$hasil = $KMP->KMPSearch($katas,$teks['positive_keyword']);
$total += count($hasil);
 echo "Kata yang dicari adalah : ".$katas."<br/>";
echo "Jumlah kata yang ditemukan : ".count($hasil)."<br/>";
echo "Yaitu pada posisi string ke : ";
foreach($hasil as $h) echo $h." ";
 echo "<br/>";
 }
echo "<div style='width:600px;'>";
 echo nl2br(str_replace($katas,"<font color='red'>".$katas."</font>",$teks['positive_keyword']));
echo "</div>";
echo $total;
}
```

Comment: You need to show your code/query if you want an answer.

Comment: @kainaw sorry I forgot to put the code but I've edited it..

Comment: You cannot do `foreach($kata as $kata)`. That overwrites your array with the first element of the array. I suggest making the array a plural, such as `$katas` or `$katai`. Then, you can use `foreach($katas as $kata)`.

Comment: @kainaw  It's still same eventhough I've implemented your suggestion  `foreach($kata as $katas)` .  And `$hasil = $KMP->KMPSearch($katas,$teks['positive_keyword']);`

Comment: Did you get all the other instances of `$kata` that should be `$katas` now? I see one in the if statement and another couple trailing an echo. Previously, your array became a single element after the first step through the foreach. So, it could only count 1. That is why I said that should be fixed. That doesn't mean it is the only problem.

Comment: @kainaw yes I have.. but the important thing in this code is `$hasil = $KMP->KMPSearch($katas,$teks['positive_keyword'])`. And I try to count all the total the same words `$total += count($hasil);`. but it didn't give the correct result. It's supposed to be 2 same words but the result is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the lack of information from you part.

you may count repetide rows by grouping then and get only those who has more than 1 count at group.

like this

Having this poor schema:

```
create table tb_keyword
( id int primary key auto_increment,
  keyword varchar(50)
 );

 insert into tb_keyword
 values( null, 'method'),(null, 'algorithm');
```

You may :

```
SELECT keyword, count(1) as times
from tb_keyword
group by keyword having  count(1) > 1
```

Which will return the keywords who appear be more than once in `tb_keyword`

Comment: will reformulate the answer

Comment: I really appreciete if you wanna help me to solve the problem.